# PHP exec node dynamic script from memory

Tags: php, node.js

I'm trying to run code through Node.js from PHP without touching the file system (the disk). Is this possible?

#### What I'm doing

```
<?php

function renderJs($script) {
  $path = __DIR__.'/'.md5($script).'.js';
  file_put_contents($path, $script);
  $rendered = `node $path`;
  unlink($path);

  return $rendered;
}

$val = renderJs('console.log(1+1)'); // 2
```

#### What I'd like to avoid

- Having to save the file to disk
- Installing additional PHP extensions (such as V8js)

Ideally, it'd be something like

```
$magicBlob = php_magic($script);
$rendered = `node $magicBlob`;
```

I can't just eval it as in

```
$rendered = `node --eval "$script"`;
```

because the script might have quotes that would break my outer quoting.

Comment: You should be able to [pipe code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to Node and have the results, if any, streamed back. Be **extremely careful** when allowing people to execute arbitrary code on your system. I'd want this sandboxed aggressively.

Answer (score 1):

using [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) works for me:

```
$js = <<<EOF

hello = function (name) {
    console.log('`Hello there '+name+"!!`");
}

hello('PHP');
EOF;

$rendered = system("node --eval ".escapeshellarg($js));
```

I don't know how good of an idea that is, but...